# How to iterate over several list/names in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm simply trying to make those three tasks into one, but can't find a proper way to do it.

```yaml
- name: "Create directories for virtual users"
  ansible.builtin.file:
    dest: "/var/ftp_clients/{{ item.name }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    owner: ftp
    group: ftp
  with_items: "{{ ftp_users }}"

- name: "Create import dir for virtual users"
  ansible.builtin.file:
    dest: "/var/ftp_clients/{{ item.name }}/import"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    owner: ftp
    group: ftp
  with_items: "{{ ftp_users }}"

- name: "Create export for virtual users"
  ansible.builtin.file:
    dest: "/var/ftp_clients/{{ item.name }}/export"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    owner: ftp
    group: ftp
  with_items: "{{ ftp_users }}"
```

with the folowing variable:

```yaml
ftp_users:
  - name: client1
    password: toto
  - name: client2
    password: toto
  - name: client3
    password: toto
```

The goal is only to create the directory for each client, and every client has to have an `import` and `export` subfolder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using a [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) of the two lists (of directories and users) and the [`format`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.format) filter.

```yaml
- name: Create directories for virtual users
  ansible.builtin.file:
    dest: "{{ item.0 | format(item.1.name) }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    owner: ftp
    group: ftp
  loop: "{{ _directories | product(ftp_users) }}"
  vars:
    _directories:
      - /var/ftp_clients/%s
      - /var/ftp_clients/%s/import
      - /var/ftp_clients/%s/export
```

After running it, you should get the expected directories structure:

```
/var/ftp_clients/
├── client1
│   ├── export
│   └── import
├── client2
│   ├── export
│   └── import
└── client3
    ├── export
    └── import
```

Comment: I didn't find any explaination on the "%s" variable, can you explain how it is defined ?

Comment: @LouisGromb: first sentence of the `format` docs I linked: _Apply the given values to a [printf-style](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) format string, like string `%` values._, then If you follow the link on the text _printf-style_, you'll find the table for all the symbols.